# Why do I get permission denied every time I try to ssh from an amazon ec2 server to another linux host?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 base instance, and they usually have password authentication disable in the sshd service.  They only authenticate with key.  The situation I have is every time I try to ssh into another linux host that authenticate with password I get the following message:

> Warning: Permanently added
>   'customerstg.domain.net'
>   (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied
>   (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Sorry to bother everyone.  I found the issue of my situation.  In my EC2 server, under the /root/.ssh/ directory is a file called config.

This file had the following settings:

> StrictHostKeyChecking no
>     CheckHostIP no
>
> PasswordAuthentication no

I change the PasswordAuthentication  from **no** to **yes**.

And that fixed the situation.  I hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the remote host's user's .ssh directory? IIRC, they must be 700 to work properly. If you're coming from a Linux host, then permissions on the local id_rsa/dsa file(private key) must be 600.